# Swift 4; coredata context.delete is not deleting

Tags: core-data

I looked for all exaples and checked all the types and objects. All looking fine. But ... the code below doesn't delete the data. No error and all print statements are indicating that the record should be deleted.The deleteDeelnemer is exactly the object I wanted to delete. Print statement succesfull was printed and no catch error.

My question is how I can debug what goes wrong? Any tips?

```
  print("trying to delete .... \(String(describing: deleteDeelnemer!))")
  context.delete(deleteDeelnemer!)
  do {
        try context.save()
        print("Delete saved succesfull")
     } catch {
        print("Error saving delete with error: \(error)")
     }
```

Comment: how do you check that object was or wasn't deleted?

Comment: With a fetchrequest in a tableview.
I have a tabelview which copies the selected records (records with a checkmark) into another table. All those copied records I show in a new table view. When a checkmark is removed, also the record should be removed from that copie table. 
So in the answer to your question is that I have a tableview on that table.

Comment: Entity&TableView: DeelnemersBestand = all contacts
Entity&Tableview: Deelnemers = checkmarked from Deelnemersbestand